# ZBAR iPhone SDK issue.

Tags: iphone, sdk, barcode

I have an app that uses the Zbar SDK I have everything up and running and it scans QR codes great. However when I try to scan UPC-A barcodes (Grocery stuff) it comes back with a completely different number than is on the barcode.

For example: I scan 03800051156
I get as a result: 156749328

As you can see completely different!

```
- (IBAction)scanButtonTapped
{
    // ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

    // EXAMPLE: Set UPC-A
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_UPCA
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 1];

    // present and release the controller
    [self presentModalViewController: reader
                            animated: YES];
    [reader release];
}


- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    // ADD: get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
    [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
        break;

    //URL
    NSString *urlString = symbol.data;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    [scanWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

    NSLog(@"Type UPC %d", symbol.type);

    NSLog(@"Reader UPC %d", urlString);
    AppDataObject* theDataObject = [self theAppDataObject];
    theDataObject.UPC = urlString;

    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
    resultText.text = symbol.data;
    // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    // ADD Load the ProductInfo view after a slight delay to let the other VC resign. 
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadProduct) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

Comment: That is bizarre, what kind of device are you reading with?  You might want to take out the "setSymbology" line when you set up the reader(Not sure if that would have an adverse effect).  It is UPCA enabled by default.  Also, try logging "symbol.typeName" in the "didFinishPickingMedia...." method to see if the code type is being recognized.

Comment: iPhone 4, EAN-13 is the default I enabled UPC-A but it's still giving me the same weird output. I removed the setSymbology and NADA. Also I am logging symbol.type (see code) and I'm getting UPC 12 which is UPC-A :( Before it was returning EAN-13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're logging `urlString` as a decimal, so you're printing the pointer value of `urlString`, not the value of the actual string.

Try:

```
NSLog(@"Reader UPC %@", urlString);
```

Comment: I figured this one out a LONG time ago. I had copied and pasted the NSlog without changing that. Silly mistake.